Can I travel to another country when my nationality hasn't been established yet?
I was born in Wurzburg Germany and live in the US. I lost my social security card and I went to the office to get a new one and they told me that I couldn't have a new card until I get my nationality established. I told the lady at the office that I served in the US Navy for years and that I was an American citizen.
She explained to me that when I turned 18 I was supposed to establish my nationality: either American citizenship German citizenship or dual citizenship. I had no idea about that.
I'm taking an early retirement and I want to go back to Germany to visit. How can I prove I am citizen and get a passport?

So what's your question? If the US doesn't believe you're a US citizen - you won't get a US passport. If Germany doesn't believe you're a German citizen - you won't get a German passport. You cannot travel without a passport.

What citizenship did your parents have? If both were not german, then you are not a german citizen. Please add relevant information into the existing question (Use the 'edit' linke).

Würzburg has (or had) a US military base. If one (or both) of your parents served in the US military, then you need to aquire their service records.

Have you read https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/travel-legal-considerations/us-citizenship/Acquisition-US-Citizenship-Child-Born-Abroad.html ?

Have you ever had a passport issued by Germany or the US?  Where did you join the navy?  Did you never cross an international border before or after joining?

Oops, my previous comment should say "Did you never cross an international border before joining or or after leaving?" -- because military personnel traveling on orders typically do not need passports.

If you are a US citizen (and got your SS card as a US citizen), you should be able to request a replacement SS card online. Did you try doing that?

Is your question mainly about getting a Social Security card or getting a US (and/or German) passport?

when I turned 18 I was supposed to establish my nationality: either American citizenship German citizenship or dual citizenship This is utterly, utterly, utterly incorrect. The lady has her head up her ass.

@user102008 has completely explained the situation. Just tap for a replacement.

The lady at the office is wrong about "establishing" your citizenship at 18 -- it's a common misunderstanding.  If you were a US citizen at birth, you are almost certainly still a US citizen, independently of any other nationality you may have had when you were born and regardless of whether you subsequently lost that nationality or still have it.
If you are a US citizen (which I suppose you must be because otherwise you wouldn't be able to live legally in the US without a green card or some sort of visa) then you can get a US passport and use it to travel to Germany.  If you are also a German citizen, however, you should probably get a German passport as well and use that to enter Germany and the US passport to enter the US.
If you have ever had a passport in the past then the issuing of the passport effectively established your nationality as that of the issuing country.  There is no formal way to establish dual nationality except by independently establishing each nationality separately.  And, once again, there is no requirement to do that at age 18, neither in US nor German law.  If you were born a dual citizen and haven't lost either nationality then you are still eligible to get a passport from both countries, no matter how old you are.
You don't need a social security card to get a US passport; you just need to know the number.  If you need the social security card for some other reason, you can "establish" your US citizenship with a consular report of birth abroad.  If you don't have that, you'll need to show evidence that you acquired US citizenship at birth through one of your parents.  You'll need the same documentary evidence of US citizenship to get your passport.

@David Jacobs As someone born in occupied Germany but has only ever been 100% American I feel your pain. Listen to phoog's answer, the lady is just wrong. I can't tell you how many times someone in the government has told me something wrong about my circumstance. I almost always have to escalate it until I get someone that knows what they're talking about.

@MiniRagnarok I think this is worth adding as another answer so it doesn't get lost amongst other comments

@CriticizingSEisbannable Germany has been allowing dual citizenship for quite some time. E.g. (but not limited to) for children where only one of the parents is a German citizen.

@CriticizingSEisbannable several countries with restrictive laws on dual nationality have no restrictions on those who acquired another nationality at birth, or at least looser restrictions.  I don't know much about German nationality law, but my understanding is that this was the case even decades ago before the present less restrictive provisions were enacted.  A person born in Germany to one German parent and one US parent could well be a dual citizen.  As of about three months ago, Germany removed the restrictions on dual nationality more generally.

@Jan and now Germany allows it for more or less anyone: "The Nationality Modernisation Act (German: "Staatsangehörigkeitsmodernisierungsgesetz") was promulgated on 26 March 2024.[107] and, with two exceptions, came into force three months later, on 27 June 2024. Dual citizenship is now allowed without restrictions.[108][109]" (from Wikipedia)

@CriticizingSEisbannable: No country on Earth "does not allow dual citizenship". Every country on Earth has laws that provide for some cases where someone has its citizenship while the person is simultaneously the citizen of another country according to that country's law. German law has never restricted the citizenship of a child born to a German citizen father, based on the child having another citizenship (e.g. US citizenship) at birth; such a child would continue to have dual citizenship for life, if they don't acquire another citizenship after birth or join a foreign military.

@MiniRagnarok my sister was once informed by a US immigration officer that having dual nationality was "unconstitutional."  It's important to remember that government officers also suffer from human fallibility, and that even though they wield the authority of the state they may nonetheless be mistaken about various provisions of its laws.

I feel this doesn't really answer the question, there is a difference between being a citizen and convincing the government you are a citizen.

my sister was once informed by a US immigration officer that having dual nationality was "unconstitutional."  It's funny.  Some official once told me in shock "You CAN'T have TWO passports?!" and I said "That's fine, I have N"  :)  People make mistakes, don't worry about it and move on.

@PeterGreen "there is a difference between being a citizen and convincing the government you are a citizen": true, but we don't know enough to be able to say much about the prospects of convincing either government that OP is a citizen, much less about the best way to do that. For someone who has US citizenship because of birth outside the US to US-citizen parents, who does not have a CRBA or other personal evidence of US citizenship, it would be the foreign birth certificate naming the parents along with evidence of the parents' US citizenship.

@PeterGreen but for someone who has taken or is about to take early retirement from the US military, it's hard to imagine that there isn't some other personal document that would serve as direct evidence of US citizenship.  As to German citizenship, there's s very strong chance that OP isn't a German citizen, but if he is then the evidence would similarly be a birth certificate plus evidence of the German parent's German citizenship.
